# JBoss AS7. How to load some.jar before war in deployment?

Tags: deployment, jar, jboss, jboss7.x, ear

I have EAR which consist from war and jar. 

project.ear
   
....package.war

....lib

.......library.jar

library.jar should be initialized before deploying war file. 
My application.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>project</display-name>
  <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
  <module>
    <java>library.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>package.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

My jboss-deployment-structure.xml file:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <deployment>
     <dependencies>
          //some modules
      </dependencies>
  </deployment>
  <sub-deployment name="library.jar">
      <resources>
        <resource-root path="lib/library.jar"/>
      </resources>
  </sub-deployment>
  <sub-deployment name="package.war">
    <exclusions>
          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
    </exclusions>
   </sub-deployment> 
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But when JBoss deploying my app, I see next error in log file.

```
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"project.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in servi
ce jboss.deployment.unit.\"project.ear\".STRUCTURE: JB
AS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"project.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
 JBAS011037: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR [\"/C:/DEV/jbo
ss-eap-6.1/bin/content/project.ear\"], module file library.jar not found"}}
```

I need in strict loading of modules. Only when library.jar will be fully initialized, package.war should be deploying.

Comment: What is this library.jar? some kind of deployment? ejb/cdi archive maybe? Or just plain some code that needs to be on classpath?

Comment: @ctomc It's custom library with java code and some spring contexts. I'm tried to move library.jar from lib directory to root of EAR. But. initialize-in-order works how should not. It's not guarantee, that jar file was fully initialized before war deployment. In library.jar I have spring JMX setting. When my war is deploying, it can not find mbeans because they is not initialized. What can be good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already told before, I have to initiliaze spring JMX settings before another configuration. Spring parent context is a great way for solving this issue. Just define parentContextKey as you need and Spring will do everything itself.

https://spring.io/blog/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/

Answer (score 0):

Separating your JMX beans setup to other deployment unit (like SAR or WAR) and setting this deployment as a EAR's dependency could to the trick.